# Why TDateTimePicker doesn't allow minimal DateTime without ShowCheckbox?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I tried to unify the `Date` in all `TDateTimePicker` used for `Time`, somewhere on 0 and somewhere on 2 or 1.1.1900 (minimal sql date) according to usage. (I know it's useless, it just bothers me, a lot of programmers definitely know that feeling.) I found out that then I can't set `Time` to midnight and this error keeps comming up.

> You must be in ShowCheckbox mode to set to this date.

It is because of the conditions in the `SetTime` and `SetDate` where `CheckEmptyDate` is called. Here is an excerpt from the documentation.

> CheckEmptyDate is called automatically when DateTime is assigned a
>   value that represents a time and not a date value (or Date is assigned
>   a value of 0).

Which is not true. `CheckEmptyDate` is called in `SetDate` and `SetEndDate` and not in `SetDateTime` and it only works for `SetEndTime`, in `SetDate` it is called if `Time` is empty.

> TDateTimePicker overrides CheckEmptyDate to clear the check box
>   associated with the calendar, or raise an EDateTimeError if the
>   ShowCheckbox property is false. **This allows TDateTimePicker to
>   represent time values that do not include a date portion**.

How exactly should this work? I tried to create new component derived from `TDateTimePicker` and changed visibility of `DateTime` to `public` set it to `0.0` and everything works. Even though `CheckEmptyDate` is virtual, I can't simply overwrite it, because it's not called in `SetTime`, which is private.

```
procedure TDateTimePicker.SetTime(Value: TTime);
var
  LDateTime: TDateTime;
begin
  if Abs(Frac(FDateTime)) <> Abs(Frac(Value)) then
  begin
    LDateTime := Value;
    ReplaceDate(LDateTime, FDateTime);
    if LDateTime = 0.0 then
    begin
      if not FShowCheckbox then
        raise EDateTimeError.CreateRes({$IFNDEF CLR}@{$ENDIF}SNeedAllowNone);
      FChecked := False;
      Invalidate;
    end
    else
      SetDateTime(LDateTime);
  end;
end;
```

I know I can set `Date` or `Time` to a value other than 0 if I don't use it. However I don't unserstand, what is the reason for all this? I didn't go through the whole implementation, so I must be missing something, because it makes no sense.

Comment: FWIW it seems totally illogical to me too.

Comment: Things are even worse in Rio: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-23256